# WebForms/ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I just updated a WebForms/ASP.NET MVC 3 hybrid application to use mvc3 and the razor view engine.  Everything seemed to be working fine however, now when I use `Html.ActionLink()` my links do not get resolved correctly or something?

For Example:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

generates an anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="/?action=Create&amp;controller=Network">Create New</a>
```

instead of what I would expect:

```
<a href="/Network/Create">Create New</a>
```

Here is the controller action method:

```
public class NetworkController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Create() {
       return View(new Network());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Could you show your routing configuration as this is probably related to it.

Comment: Could you include your routing configuration? Everyone that googles or comes across this problem does not have enough information from what you've provided to see if they have the same issue. This question (in its current form) is useless to the community as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, there's definitely something up with your route config.

The routing engine does two things; it resolves a URL to a set of routevalues (which is what's happening when you type /Network/Create in your browser and it goes to the correction action) and it resolves a set of routevalues to a URL (which is what happens when you do URL generation like in an actionlink).  The routes are tested in order, and the first one that declares a match wins, which means you don't always have the same result both directions if you haven't set them up right.

Recommend doing route testing w/ the [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/) route helpers, which may help you narrow down your problem.  Also, it's generally a bad practice (or at least unreliable) to rely on the "ambient" route values, as @Chad Moran suggested, if you choose oneof the more explicit overloads of ActionLink you may hve better results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure everything is set up correctly with routing?  This seems to indicate that no route was found where `controller` and `action` were sufficient routes.

Comment: Copy and paste the Route Registration (by default this would be in your global.asax)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not supplying the Controller parameter of the method it's based on context.  Is this call inside of another controller's context?

Try this...

> @Html.ActionLink("Create New",
>   "Create", "Network")